# For anidado en java

Tags: java

estoy con un ejercicio de **`java`** y no estaría entendiendo como funciona, se la figura que imprime, pero no entiendo como funcionan, he intentado hacer prueba de escritorio, pero no me cierra, o no lo estoy entendiendo, muchas gracias!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 5; j > i; j--) {
       System.out.print("@");
  }
   System.out.println(");
}
```

Comment: dibuja una piramide invertida.. o un triangulo en realidad. cual es la pregunta?

Comment: que no entiendo como funcionan los for, no pude realizar la prueba de escritorio para que me de esa piramide, y tampoco entiendo porque j es mayor que i

Comment: A simple vista tu código debe generar un triangulo, bueno pero para esto debes corregir  la linea `System.out.println(");` te faltan unas comillas ", debe ser: `System.out.println("");`

Comment: el error fue mio sin querer, lo corregi, pero mi duda es esa condicion, el ejercicio lo vi resuelto y queria saber porque J > I

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Al estar trabando ya con ciclos, considero que has visto algo de teoría, de igual forma te comparto un link de [w3schools-for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp), donde estoy segura aprenderás mucho más.

Si bien, mencionas que tu duda es: ¿Por qué ***j > i***? Veamos.

En tu primer for (`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`) estas declarando que **i=0** y que este ciclo se ejecutará siempre que ***i*** sea menor a 5, es decir que cuando ***i*** valga 5, este ciclo ya no dará más, debido a que 5 nunca sera menor a 5.

En tu segundo for (`for (int j = 5; j > i; j--)`) declaras que **j=5** y que el ciclo se ejecutará siempre que **j>i**. Veamos, en su primer iteración del primer for ***i*** es igual a 0, lo cual cumple con la condición de que ***i*** sea menor que 5, y hace que entre al segundo for.

En la primer iteración:

- ***i*** es igual a 0.
- ***j*** es igual a 5.

Por lo que tenemos que 5 es mayor a 0 ó ***j*** es mayor a ***i***, lo cual es la condición de tu segundo for: **j>i**

Como se cumple la condición, entra al cuerpo del segundo for e imprime `@`. Como tu estas dando un decremento a ***j*** con `j--`, en su segunda vuelta del segundo for, ***j*** ya vale 4, pero sigue siendo mayor que ***i***, por lo tanto imprimirá otras arroba.

Tu segundo for dará tantas vueltas sean necesarias hasta no cumplir con la condición, es decir ***j*** valdrá **5,4,3,2,1,0**. Es decir, dará en total 5 vueltas hasta romper el que ***j*** ya no sea mayor que ***i***. Cuando llegue a 0 ya no cumplirá con la condición y por lo tanto ya no entrará a imprimir una sexta arroba, debido a que **j=0** no es mayor a **i=0**. Entonces sale del segundo for, el programa sigue su camino y ahora da un salto de linea con el `System.out.println("");` que es parte del primer for.

Ahora, gracias al incremento que tienes de `i++` para tu primer for, ***i*** ya vale 1, se cumple la condición de que **i < 5** y entra nuevamente al segundo for. El segundo for ahora dará las vueltas necesarias hasta que ya no se cumpla su condición (j>i), los valores que tendrá serán **5,4,3,2,1** el ciclo se romperá cuando ***j*** valga 1, ya que **j=1** no es mayor que **i=1**. Sale del segundo for y da un salto de linea.

.....

Esto se repetirá hasta que ***i*** valga 5, ya que la condición del primer for es **i>5**, a lo cual 5>5 es falso y por lo tanto ya no se ejecutara ningún for.

Las iteraciones serán las siguientes:

```
valor de i: 0.  valores de j: 543210   las arrobas que imprime @@@@@
valor de i: 1.  valores de j: 54321    las arrobas que imprime @@@@
valor de i: 2.  valores de j: 5432     las arrobas que imprime @@@
valor de i: 3.  valores de j: 543      las arrobas que imprime @@
valor de i: 4.  valores de j: 54       las arrobas que imprime @
```

Espero haber sido clara.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya entendí como funciona!

Comment: @frodriguez12 no debes añadir una respuesta para dar las gracias. La forma de agradecer una respuesta es votarla positivamente, y aceptar la respuesta si consideras que te ha ayudado. Un saludo y bienvenido al sito.

Answer (score 2):

Para entender el for anidado debes entender primero el for normal.

El for normal funciona de la siguiente manera:
(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

En la primera parte del for: inicializas la variable i con valor de 0. **int i = 0;**
En la segunda parte del for: le estas diciendo que esa variable i, que vale actualmente 0, no debera pasar de 5 **i < 5;**
En la tercera parte del for: le estas diciendo que la variable i, debe incrementarse en uno cada ves que se repita el ciclo for **i++**

Entonces podemos entender que el ciclo for se repetira iniciando con el valor de i = 0, tendra como valor maximo el 5, y se incrementara de 1 en 1. Por lo cual lo que este dentro del for se realizara 5 veces.

Ahora bien el for anidando funciona incluyendo un for dentro de otro for.
Si al primero le estas diciendo que se incremente, al segundo "en tu ejemplo" le estas diciendo que decremente, es decir disminuya de uno en uno.

for (int j = 5; j > i; j--)
En la primer parte del for le dices que la variable j vale 5. **int j = 5**
En la segunda parte del for le dices que la variable j debe ser mayor a la variable i **i < 5;**
En la tercera parte del for le dices que la variable j debe ir en decremento. **i--**

Ahora bien explicando ya los dos for que manejas en tu ejemplo el anidando es simple.
Si el primer for repite lo que esta dentro de el 5 veces, y el segundo for repite las veces que se maneja en i pero en decremento.

- La variable i inicialmente vale 0, y se incrementa hasta 5.
- La variable j inicialmente vale 5, y se decrementa hasta el valor de i.

Es decir cuando i valga 1, j iniciara en 5 pero tendra como limite i, es decir 1.
Cuando i valga 2, j iniciara con 5 pero tendra como limite i, es decir 2.
Y asi sucesivamente hasta concluir el ciclo limite del for, que en este caso es 5 por tu variable i.

Espero haberte aclarado tu duda, saludos!.